# Python Panda SQL Subtract in Statement

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to do a subtract within an SQLite statement but within Pandas in Python.

```
def get_profit_year_data(year):
    con = sqlite3.connect(str(DBFILE))
    pftydata = pd.read_sql_query("(SELECT Month, SUM(Value) as Value FROM Figures WHERE Type='Expense' AND Year=?) - (SELECT Month, SUM(Value) as Value FROM Figures WHERE Type='Sale' AND Year=?)", con, params={year})
    print(pftydata)
```

I am getting a Syntax error on the above code.

I have one table with the following columns ID, Type (Sale or Expense), Date, Year, Month, Value.

I need want my sql query to return the below example, the Month and then the Value of Sale - Expense for the Month. And for each month in the table. If that makes sense!

January 50
February 100
March 65

Would greatly appreciate and help or guidance of where to go.

Answer (score 0):

I got it in the end!

```
def get_profit_year_data(year):
    con = sqlite3.connect(str(DBFILE))
    pftydata = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT Month, SUM(SValue-EValue) as Profit FROM Figures WHERE Year=? GROUP BY Month ORDER BY [ID]", con, params={year})
    print(pftydata)
```